# Enable bluetooth Lenovo t430s kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, bluetooth, lenovo

I am trying to enable bluetooth on my t430s; however, the adapter doesn't show up.  As root, I have tried 
      echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/bluetooth_enable
however, I get a message
      `-su: /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/bluetooth_enable: Permission denied`

I've installed bluetooth support.
Can someone help me out.
Thanks.

Here are the outputs of commands requested in the comment by @Jeremy31.  Thanks.

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b2da Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1058:0820 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
berman (master *) sql $ lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             446409  10 bnep,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
berman (master *) sql $ uname -a
Linux t430s 3.16.0-55-generic #74~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 17 10:15:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
berman (master *) sql $ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
berman (master *) sql $ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8195]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
berman (master *) sql $ dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.121077] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.174807] pnp 00:01: [Firmware Bug]: PNP resource [mem 0xfed10000-0xfed13fff] covers only part of 0000:00:00.0 Intel MCH; extending to [mem 0xfed10000-0xfed17fff]
[    1.455201] psmouse serio1: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[   18.384651] rtl8192ce: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
[   22.615162] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   22.615174] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   22.615179] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   22.615181] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   22.615187] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   22.617601] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   22.617608] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   22.617611] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   22.781609] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   22.781612] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   22.781619] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
berman (master *) sql $
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; lsmod | grep bluetooth; uname -a; rfkill list all; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` Thanks

Comment: Has bluetooth worked prior to installing kubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Never tried it on the laptop until the other day (my main machine died).

Comment: It is possible that there is no bluetooth on the machine.  If you want, you can remove the bottom cover and look at the sticker on the wireless card, if it has bluetooth it will show a MAC ID and a BT ID as I see no sign of bluetooth from your terminal results

Comment: Oops.  Looked at the order & there is no bluetooth mentioned.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the instructions of the second post on this [Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2269744)

Comment: That seems to have enabled bluetooth.  Unfortunately, even after a reboot it can't find a device.